# Help with Mozart 6 bar long chord progression?

Tags: theory, chords, mozart

[image: Mozart clarinet concerto]

Can someone please explain what chords progressions are happening in this 6 measures ?

My guess is that the first measure is a A chord and the last one is a V going to I .
My confusing is regarding the middle 4 measures.
Especially the 3rd measure...is it supposed to be an A7 ? If so why...?
If not please explain what exactly is happening in those 4 measures ?Thank you

Comment: What instruments are playing in this excerpt, in order? The ones with no sharps in their key signatures look like transposing instruments, but I've seen that some transposing instruments always lack key signatures regardless of the key of the piece. Also, the last bar looks like I to V instead--A major to E major chords.

Comment: Flute , Bassoon , French Horn in A , Clarinet in A , Violin 1 , 2 , Viola ,Cello , Bass.   The very last chord is a V going into the 1 in the following messure,

Answer (score 2):

Bar 1: A-E-A-E

Bar 2: A

Bar 3: A7 - A+5

Bar 4: D - B7 without the note B

Bar 5: The tone E (V) without chord but upwards scale movement and cromatic movement down, on beat 3 creating an E7 and on beat 4 creating an A chord

Bar 6: A chord with E bass, and then E chord on beat 4

---

As a whole bar 1,2 and 3 are centered around the A, tonic

bar 4, D and B7, subdominant followed by the dominant's dominant

bar 5 and 6 centered around E, dominant

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. Could you perhaps kindly explain bar 3...A7-A5+ ..why and how it works ?

Comment: I guess A7 , A+5 leads to  D and B7 leads to E ...but I`m not sure what is the conection beetwen D and B7 ...?

Comment: We are in A major, then in the third bar the seventh is added which makes the A7 chord work as a secondary dominant leading towards D. But instead of keeping the seventh Mozart changes the note g to the augmented fitth, the e sharp, which leads to f sharp, which is the third in the D major chord. Very delicate and nice. I think typical Mozart to make something like that.

Comment: The note d in the D major chord is augmented, changed to d sharp which leeads to e in the next bar. By only changing that note d to d sharp it is suddenly a B7 without the note b, the dominant's dominant. Another delicate detail by Mozart.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and detailed answers Mr. @LarsPeterSchultz ! It makes so much sense now ! You are very knowledgeable

Comment: Thanks. Actually you could argue that the B7 without the b is kind of an augmented D, so it is still kind of a subdominant, but, as I said, you could also say it is a dominant's dominant which makes sense in my opinion.

Comment: I desagree with B7 without a B. The bass is on F#, so why is it not F#dim, or F#m(b5)?

Comment: It is not a complete F#dim. It has only 3 notes F#, A and D# and the function is clearly to lead up to E in the next bar.